# Стилистический прием

Tags: стилистика

Добрый день!

Как называется стилистический прием, когда в одном предложении специально употребляется и высокая, и сниженная лексика? Напр., "Сытно жрать - отнюдь не главная цель человеческой жизни".

Спасибо!

Answer (score 1):

Нарушение лексической сочетаемости. Другого названия не знаю.
А вообще это может быть не только высокий и низкий стили, а, скажем, научный и просторечный. Наиболее известный представитель этого направления - Амвросий Амбруазович Выбегалло из "Понедельник начинается в субботу" Стругацких.

Answer (score 0):

Может быть,  здесь просто выражено авторское отношение?